# AWS EC2: how to change setting to be "keep volume after instance termination"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS EC2: For an running instance, how to change setting to be "keep volume after instance termination"?

When terminating an instance, its volumes can be deleted automatically. EBS volumes must be always kept until deleted manually. How to keep the volumes? Could not find related setting
in instance info/action page.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can do this using AWS console. Instead you can use AWS CLI's [modify-instance-attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-instance-attribute.html) as described in [Change the root volume of a running instance to persist using the command line](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#delete-on-termination-cli).